# Anexar Arquivo no Gmail via Intent

Tags: android, android-activity

Estou com um problema... Quando eu tento abrir o Gmail via Intent pra anexar um arquivo, ele aparece a parte de escrever um e-mail novo, mas ele não anexa o meu arquivo. O PDF está dentro de uma pasta do próprio app com este caminho.:(/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/teste.com.br.cartaovisitateste/files/business.pdf), porém ele não pega o PDF lá de dentro pra anexar no e-mail Alguém ai sabe o que pode ser?
Meu código da Intent do Gmail:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "");
//  funciona parcialmente, mas ele diz que encontrou um arquivo vazio
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/teste.com.br.cartaovisitateste/files/business.pdf"));
//  it does not work too
Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "business.pdf"));
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, String.valueOf(Hawk.get("registro_nome")).concat(" Business Card"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Enviando e-mail..."));
```

Comment: Não sei que tipo de aplicação você está desenvolvendo, mas provavelmente a pessoa irá ter uma interface para selecionar o arquivo, para depois ser enviado. Então aconselho a você já pegar o endereço do arquivo através do método "onActivityResult", esse endereço que você colocou de forma estática vária muito a depender da versão do android. Se o seu código apresentou alguma erro, acrescente junto a sua postagem, para melhor entendimento do problema.

Comment: A priori, para teste, minha aplicação está funcionando desta maneira:
1º - eu tenho uma lib que ele gera um arquivo PDF pegando um layout que eu tenho
2º - eu já abro a aplicação, e ele internamente já gera o PDF da tela
3º - eu tenho um botão pra compartilhar por e-mail, e ai eu clicaria ali e iria compartilhar por e-mail
Na verdade eu não tenho uma aplicação, ele faz tudo sem uma tela

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça dessa forma:

```
File f = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/teste.com.br.cartaovisitateste/files/business.pdf");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(f));
```

Comment: Funcionou, valeu!